# Wordpress website showing error with no problems in debug mode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on a website and I see a big error page showing in the screenshot. On my machine the website looks fine but if i open it in Incognito it does not work.

https://kirtis.de/. - This is the website

I have tried the debuggig plugins and folowed some vidoes to find out problems but no success.
I have also uninstall the plugin social media plugin but still seeing the same error.

Can any one help?

The error looks like this :

@font-face{font-family:helveticabold;src:url(fonts/helvetica_bold_0-webfont.eot);src:url(fonts/helvetica_bold_0-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype') , url(fonts/helvetica_bold_0-webfont.woff) format('woff') , url(fonts/helvetica_bold_0-webfont.ttf) format('truetype') , url(fonts/helvetica_bold_0-webfont.svg#helveticabold) format('svg');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:helveticaregular;src:url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.eot);src:url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype') , url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.woff) format('woff') , url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.ttf) format('truetype') , url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.svg#helveticaregular) format('svg');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:helvetica-light;src:url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.eot);src:url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype') , url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.woff) format('woff') , url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.ttf) format('truetype') , url(fonts/helvetica_0-webfont.svg#helvetica-light) format('svg');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:helveticaneue-light;src:url(fonts/helveticaneue-light.eot);src:url(fonts/helveticaneue-light.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype') , url(fonts/helveticaneue-light.woff) format('woff') , url(fonts/helveticaneue-light.ttf) format('truetype') , url(fonts/helveticaneue-light.svg#helveticaneue-light) format('svg');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}body{margin:0;padding:0}.clear{clear:both}.space{clear:both;padding:30px 0 0;width:100%;float:left}.like_txt{margin:30px 0 0;padding:0;color:#12a252;font-family:helveticaregular;font-size:20px;line-height:20px;text-align:center}.like_txt a{color:#12a252}.sfsibeforpstwpr iframe,.sfsiaftrpstwpr iframe{max-width:none}.sfwp_fivestar_ul li{display:block;padding-right:20px}.shwthmbfraftr{margin-top:5px!important}label.toglpstpgsbttl{float:left;margin-top:5px!important}.tab_3_icns.shwthmbfraftr .cstmdisplaysharingtxt{float:left}.tab6 ul.enough_waffling.sfsi_dsplyatend{width:24%;float:left}.tab4 ul.like_icon{margin:0;padding:20px 0 0;list-style:none;text-align:center}.tab4 ul.like_icon li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;display:inline-block}.tab4 ul.like_icon li span{margin:0;width:58px;display:block;background:url(https://kirtis.de/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-social-media-icons/images/xcount_bg.png.pagespeed.ic.Kd6rEJ4jtk.png) no-repeat;height:38px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 2px 2px;font-size:17px;text-align:center;line-height:24px;color:#5a6570}.tab4 ul.like_icon li a{color:#5a6570;text-decoration:none}.tab4 ul.enough_waffling{margin:0;padding:25px 0 27px;list-style:none;text-align:center}.tab4 ul.enough_waffling li{margin:0 22px;padding:0;list-style:none;display:inline-block}.tab4 ul.enough_waffling li span{float:left}.tab4 ul.enough_waffling li label{margin:0 0 0 20px;float:left;font-family:helveticaregular;font-size:18px;font-weight:400;text-align:center;line-height:38px;color:#5a6570}.sfsi_mainContainer .checkbox{width:31px;height:31px;background:url(https://kirtis.de/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-social-media-icons/images/xcheck_bg.jpg.pagespeed.ic.B7jkwBw_Bs.webp) no-repeat;display:inherit}.sfsi_mainContainer .radio{width:40px;height:40px;background:url(https://kirtis.de/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-social-media-icons/images/xradio_bg.png.pagespeed.ic.Lvtlv6OcEd.png) no-repeat;display:inherit}.sfsi_mainContainer .select{width:137px;height:47px;font-size:17px;background:url(https://kirtis.de/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-social-media-icons/images/xselect_bg.jpg.pagespeed.ic.0XPbw3olEW.webp) no-repeat;display:block;padding-left:16px;line-height:49px}.sfsi_mainContainer .line{background:#eaebee;height:1px;font-size:0;margin:15px 0 0;clear:both;width:100%;float:left}.specify_counts{display:block;margin-top:15px;padding-top:15px;clear:both;width:100%;float:left;border-top:1px solid #eaebee}.specify_counts .radio_section{width:30px;float:left;margin:12px 10px 0 0}.specify_counts .social_icon_like{width:54px;float:left;margin:0 15px 0 0}.specify_counts .social_icon_like ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;text-align:center}.specify_counts .social_icon_like li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;display:inline-block}.specify_counts .social_icon_like li span{margin:0;width:54px;display:block;background:url(https://kirtis.de/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-social-media-icons/images/xcount_bg.jpg.pagespeed.ic.PvQwqqLBCp.webp) no-repeat;height:24px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 2px 2px;font-family:helveticaregular;font-size:16px;text-align:center;line-height:24px;color:#5a6570}.specify_counts .social_icon_like li a{color:#5a6570;text-decoration:none}.specify_counts .listing{width:88%;margin-top:-5px;display:inherit;float:left}.specify_counts .listing ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;text-align:left}.specify_counts .listing li{margin:15px 0 0;padding:0;list-style:none;clear:both;line-height:39px;font-size:17px}.specify_counts .listing li span{float:left;margin-right:20px}.specify_counts .listing li .input{background:#e5e5e5;box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #dcdcdc inset;border:0;padding:10px;margin-left:25px}.specify_counts .listing li .input_facebook{width:288px;background:#e5e5e5;box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #dcdcdc inset;border:0;padding:10px;margin-left:16px}.save_button{width:450px;padding-top:30px;clear:both;margin:auto}.save_button a{background:#12a252;text-align:center;font-size:23px;color:#fff!important;display:block;padding:11px 0;text-decoration:none}.save_button a:hover{background:#079345}.tab5 ul.share_icon_order{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;text-align:left}.tab5 ul.share_icon_order li{margin:22px 6px 0 0;padding:0;list-style:none;float:left;line-height:37px}.tab5 ul.share_icon_order li:last-child{margin:22px 0 0 3px}.tab5 .row{border-top:1px solid #eaebee;margin-top:25px;padding-top:15px;clear:both;display:block;width:100%;float:left;font-family:helveticaregular;line-height:42px}.tab5 .icons_size{position:relative}.tab5 .icons_size span{margin-right:18px;display:block;float:left;font-size:17px;font-weight:400;line-height:46px}.tab5 .icons_size span.last{margin-left:55px}.tab5 .icons_size input{width:73px;background:#e5e5e5;box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #dcdcdc inset;border:0;padding:13px 13px 12px;margin-right:18px;float:left;display:block}.tab5 .icons_size select.styled{position:absolute;left:0;width:135px;height:46px;line-height:46px}.tab5 .icons_size .field{position:relative;float:left;display:block;margin-right:20px}.tab5 .icons_size ins{margin-right:25px;float:left;font-size:17px;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none}.tab5 .icons_size ins.leave_empty{line-height:23px}.tab5 .icons_size{padding-top:15px}.tab5 ul.enough_waffling{margin:-5px 0 0;padding:0;list-style:none;text-align:center}.tab5 .new_wind .row_onl ul.enough_waffling{margin:20px 0 0 0;padding:0;list-style:none;height:38px;text-align:center;width:61%}.tab5 ul.enough_waffling li{margin:0 22px;padding:0;list-style:none;display:inline-block;float:left}.tab5 ul.enough_waffling li span{float:left}.tab5 ul.enough_waffling li label{margin:0 0 0 20px;float:left;font-family:helveticaregular;font-size:18px;font-weight:400;text-align:center;line-height:38px;color:#5a6570}.sticking p{float:left;font-size:18px!important}.sticking p.list{width:168px}.sticking p.link{margin:3px 0 0 12px;padding:0!important;float:left}.sticking

[image]

Comment: Could  you get any website to work? Could you try to make only a small change?

Comment: It isn't an error, It's raw css inside your body with `pre` tag

Comment: the wordpress install is corrupt, because even on the core urls site.com/wp-admin the raw css is printed in the body and no header, no footer, no scripts or dependencies are loaded
This install can impossibly work in the backend, hence, can not be worked on currently.

Could be entire folders are missing in your install, or somehow actions are all removed that usually bootstrap WordPress.

Backup your database if you think you have some valuable data in there, same with FTP Data, and then delete everything so to re-install WordPress, as this, for me, looks like a broken install.

Comment: I tried resetting wordpress by using wp reset plugin and restored the DB... Also tried different themes but getting the same error. Although it worked fine till yesterday evening, I uploaded a new image and it stopped working... I also deleted the added things and plugins but nothing worked.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it what was the issue?